# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL

Tags: xcode, boolean

I just inherent a new app from a previous programmer and keep on running into a **"Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'bool *') from 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') "**.

Code like such as

```
_backButtonPressed = YES;

_isEdited = YES;
```

come up with the same error. I tried *(_backButtonPressed) = YES; and
*_backButtonPressed = Yes, but both scenarios crashes the program.

Program still work if I leave it alone, but I wanted to keep the code clean.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Does `_backButtonPressed` need to be a pointer to a `BOOL`? Can it just be a `BOOL`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I wasn't the original programmer.

Answer (score 14):

My guess is that the two variables in question were declared incorrectly. For example, _backButtonPressed is probably declared as

```
BOOL* _backButtonPressed;
```

but should be

```
BOOL _backButtonPressed;
```

The crash occurs because _backButtonPress is not a pointer: if it was, there would be a statement like
_backButtonPressed = (BOOL*)malloc(sizeof(BOOL));
somewhere. If this was not done before you try to assign to 
*(_backButtonPressed), then you will see a crash.

It is easy to make the mistake of declaring BOOL* instead of BOOL, because Cocoa objects are always declared with the *

I recommend that you fix the declarations. I am pretty sure everything will work if you do that.

Comment: I have inserted the BOOL _backButtonPressed; but getting a new error.  



`Unused variable '_backButtonPressed'`

Comment: Don't insert a declaration, find the erroneous one and change that.

Comment: I won't forget...I still looking into it.